# How to handle functions that return a Result<(), E>?

Tags: rust

What is the best way to call a function is when it returns a Result with a Unit Type in Rust?

For example I have this function to copy some text to clipboard:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use cli_clipboard::{ClipboardContext, ClipboardProvider};

fn copy_to_clipboard(text:&String) -> Result<()>{
    let mut ctx = ClipboardContext::new()?;
    ctx.set_contents(text.to_owned())?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Then when I call this function I'd like to do this, but it creates a compiler warning "unused Result that must be used":

```
copy_to_clipboard(selected_value);
```

So I've ended up using the following instead which removes the warning:

```
_ = copy_to_clipboard(selected_value);
```

Just wondering if there is a better/more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Consider re-reading [the book on section 9.2: Recoverable errors with Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html), mainly the part on _propagating the errors_.

Comment: Also https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/#results-must-be-used

Answer (score 5):

> Just wondering if there is a better/more idiomatic way to do this?

Well Depends.

Since the function returns a `Result`, it's signaling that it can fail. The `()` means it has no useful return value if it succeeds (this is common for functions with only side-effects).

So the question is really what you want to do if (when?) the function fails. What you've said here is "I don't care and I want to ignore it", which is perfectly valid (though you may want to document the reasoning via a comment).

Other possibilities are handling the error (e.g. recovering, displaying an error message, ...), bubbling the error up to your own caller, panic-ing (using unwrap or expect), ...